# first integral of Duffing equation

Tags: differential

I have a differential equation: $$\ddot{\omega}+2k\dot{\omega}+2k^2{\omega}-2{\omega}^3=0$$
As I understand it's a Duffing equation, but I can't find the first integral. How can I do it? I didn't find any articles. Thanks for the help! $k$ - constant.

Comment: I assume that $\omega$ and $w$ were supposed to be the same? And that the $w$ in $2kw$ is missing a dot?

Comment: @Mankind yes, I've made a mistake,sorry